# DateTime.TryParseExact returns false

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to parse `4/27/2011 12:00:00 AM` using `M/d/yyyy H:m:s a` pattern, invariant culture and default options but it doesn't parse.

I'll be very thankful if someone will help me to realize what's wrong.

Comment: In future, it would be helpful if you'd include a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your pattern doesn't include `tt`, which is the AM/PM designator and *is* in your input text. Additionally, you want `h` for 12-hour clock rather than 24 for 24-hour clock, and it looks like you will always have two-digit minutes and seconds, so you probably just want a pattern of `M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt`.

Sample code which works:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DateTime value;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact("4/27/2011 12:00:00 AM",
                                   "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                   DateTimeStyles.None,
                                   out value))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

See MSDN for more information on [custom date and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Comment: thanks for tt, i've read somewhere that 'a' is the AM/PM designator. But it still doesn't want to parse this date with H designator for hours. why?

Comment: @lua.rasta: You've got 12, which means it would be *PM* when parsed as a 24-hour hour number... but you've also got AM. That's why my sample code uses `h` instead...

Answer (score 5):

The pattern is incorrect - there is no `a` format specifier - it should be `tt`